# Почему alert срабатывает два раза?

Tags: javascript, framework7

В общем загружаем и показываем картинку, скачанную с сервера. Проблема в том, что если сервер возвращает 404, то alert выскакивает 2 раза. Почему?

```
function view(a) {
var img = new Image();
var s = a;
myApp.showPreloader('Загружаем...');
img.src = s;
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('showimg').innerHTML = '';
    var openPhotoSwipe = function(a) {
        myApp.hidePreloader();
        myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;
        document.getElementById("check").style.display = "block";

        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
        var items = [{
            src: s,
            w: img.width,
            h: img.height
        }];
        var options = {
            showAnimationDuration: 0,
            hideAnimationDuration: 0
        };
        var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
        gallery.listen('destroy', function() {
            document.getElementById("check").style.display = "none";
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var ii = 0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {
                if (elements[ii].type == "text") {
                    elements[ii].value = "";
                }
            }
            $$(window).width() < 770 && (myApp.allowPanelOpen = !0);
        });
    };
    openPhotoSwipe();
}
img.onerror = function() {
    myApp.alert('Не найдено...');
    myApp.hidePreloader();
}}
```

Comment: Что внутри `myApp.alert` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из-за 404 может генерироваться не одна ошибка. Из-за этого может быть два 
`myApp.alert('Не найдено...');`. Как я понял, Ваш код выводит алерт только в случае ошибки, значит - их две.

Comment: А где посмотреть о чем ошибки?

Comment: В общем да, форма не верно работала и вызывала эту функцию два раза, отсюда и два алерта. Спасибо за идею)

Comment: Простите, что не ответил тогда на Ваш вопрос. Не стоит благодарности, я ничего такого существенного не сказал.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после срабатывания отключить ошибку img.onerror = null;